# i want to create an application,if i want to uninstall my application from android mobile it should ask me password?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a doubt in android. I want to create an application with security so that if any one wants to uninstall my application from my mobile it should ask them password... Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my sorry....

Uninstall is a `platform feature`, there is no way to prevent or even detect it from the application.

The problem is that your application might not even be running when the user uninstalls.

Comment: is it sure. i want to know in detail

Comment: What is sure, I found no solution to this and believe me i dook hard for it some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

What if it's installed as a system application? Then it at least can't be uninstalled as easily...